# Is there a way to get name of an argument from calling method in called method?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

The following code prints "argument".

```
void PrintNameOf(string argument)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(argument)} has value: {argument}");
}

string myString = "hello";
PrintNameOf(myString);
```

Is there a way to get "myString"?

Comment: No, because *within* the method the identifier `myString` doesn´t even eist. However outside the method you can of course use `nameof(mystring)`.

Comment: In the compiled code, `mystring` normally doesn't even exist at the callsite, never mind in the called method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do

```
void PrintNameOf(string argument, string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} has value: {argument}");
}

string myString = "hello";
PrintNameOf(myString, nameof(myString));
```